# URL working on computer but not on an android phone

Tags: android, webview, user-agent

I tried to load this url :

```
www.televisaofutebol.com/xuuby.php?chname=vh1&height=500&width=650
```

On my phone but it say that the page couldn't be loaded but it works on my computer !

So i change the user agent of my webview to simulate that I'm a computer but it didn"t work neither

```
browser.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; en-US; rv:1.9.1.8) Gecko/20100202 Firefox/3.5.8");
```

Can someone help me ? ^^

Comment: already enabled, other website works  but not this one :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to load after adding http://

```
http://www.televisaofutebol.com/xuuby.php?chname=vh1&height=500&width=650
```

Comment: no need of that.now he is changing his url.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check that `what is the Phone Screen size ?` Because here you passing parameter `height=500  and width=650` so it will `not support for all device screen size`.

First you have to `get the Default Height & Width of Device` and then base on that you can pass parameter.

Hope you will get output as per some changes.

**Best of Luck. !!!**

Comment: thanks for your help but you can try with www.televisaofutebol.com/xuuby.php?chname=vh1 it works on pc but not on a mobile . The server must certainly block mobiles and I'm looking for a way to bypass it :)

Comment: its your second query. see your question url its totally different. in that you are passing 3 params and here you want to pass only 1. so its better to ask new query or edit this question